# BotFramework User's Culture from IEventActivity

Tags: botframework

I am trying to figure out how to get user's culture from my chatbot during the OnEventActivityAsync. Our webchat posts an activity that would trigger welcome message from the bot. This welcome message must come in user's language.

Ordinarily, we would look at IMessageActivity locale attribute.

```
IMessageActivity msg = context.Activity.AsMessageActivity();
string locale = msg.Locale;
```

However, in the OnEventActivityAsync the parameter is of type IEventActivity, and it does not have locale attribute. Any ideas on how to get culture in OnEventActivityAsync?

Answer (score 0):

The BotFramework-WebChat [04.api/a.welcome-event](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/a.welcome-event) sample demonstrates sending the user's language (locale) as the event value.

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
  if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
  // When we receive DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED action, we will send an event activity using WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT
    dispatch({
      type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
      payload: {
        name: 'webchat/join',
        value: { language: window.navigator.language }
      }
    });
  }

  return next(action);
});
```

If you read the event value first, setting the locale to be used, then you will be able to send the welcome message in the user's language, as desired.

Hope of help!